# Linking back to home page in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, hyperlink, hierarchy, file-structure

So I have WordPress installed in a subdirectory of my website with permalinks set up.

I have my website set up like so:

```
-index.php
-style.css
-/contact
---index.php
-/blog
---(Wordpress installation)
```

So my problem is, whenever I use an  `<a href="../">Home</a>` to link back to my homepage, it only works from my main blog page.  If I go to a permalink post it takes me back to the blog home.

What I'm wondering is, is there a way to link back to the main page on both my blog home, and a permalink post?  If i use ../../ it works on the post, but not the blog home.

I hope I worded this clearly enough, if I missed anything please let me know.  Any help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 37):

```
<a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">Home</a>
```

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url

Comment: That only words if you want to only go home though right?  Say you wanted to go ../, then forward to contact, that wouldn't work right?

Comment: Sure it would - simply concatenate, like this: <a href="<?php echo home_url() . "/contact"; ?>">Contact</a>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `home_url` function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url

I also recommend checking out the WordPress Function reference, and use the appropriate built in functions rather than inventing your own.

Edit: Not sure if you want to go back to the main index, or the WordPress index. If you just want to link back to your first `index.php`, you can simply use `<a href="/>Home</a>`